# ComplexImage to Matrix

Tags: c#, image-processing, fft, complex-numbers, accord.net

I am working with the Accord framework.

I have transformed a few bitmaps into `ComplexImage` objects to perform 2D FFT on them(which is done). Now I would like to calculate the complex conjugates of these Fourier-transformed `ComplexImages`objects (for cross-correlation purposes).

I didn't find any tool to do this directly in the Accord framework. I tried to convert my `ComplexImage` objects into matrix using `Accord.Imaging.Converters.ImageToMatrix.Convert(input, output)`, but it only accepts `Bitmap` as input data. My problem is that I need the imaginary part of my data, hence I can't convert it to `Bitmap` to use the aforementioned Convert tool.

Does someone have a solution to either convert `ComplexImage` to a complex matrix or, even better, directly get the complex conjugate of my `ComplexImage`objects ?

Comment: ComplexImage has Data property, which is already complex matrix.